# why do properties in visual studio reference themselves with macro

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

For example:

[image: See image]

As far as i know what is happening here is that jcapimin.c's AdditionalIncludeDirectories metadata property is being set so that it can be referenced later with the %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories) macro in the compilers command line and wherever else you want.

So what I don't understand is why when something down the line retrieves this information using the %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories) macro the information retrieved needs to have %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories) stuck on the end of it

Comment: So that if it's changed later it only has to change in one place and the change will automatically be reflected in all places that use that macro.

Comment: It sounds like you are just describing what a macro does. In this situation when the macro %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories) is used somewhere the value returned will include the name of the macro itself on the end. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values of variables (properties, items, metadata, ...) are not automatically inherited in MsBuild, but instead new declarations of the same name [override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx#Anchor_6) the previous value. So if the *%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)* is not appended the new value of *AdditionalIncludeDirectories* would be just the *....\jpeg;....\jpeg\simd* part and the compiler wouldn't be able to find standard library headers etc.

The property pages like you show are just a user interface on top of msbuild, which is easy to check if you open the project file in a text editor so here's a fictive sample of what happens in MsBuild:

```
<!--Somewhere in the msbuild files with compiler options-->
<ItemGroup>
  <AdditionalIncludeDirectories Include="$(VCInstallPath)\include"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

The code in the above file is eventually included in your project file, and now you want to add directories to the compiler's include search path. Suppose you'd write

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AdditionalIncludeDirectories Include="..\jpeg"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

then the new value of *AdditionalIncludeDirectories* is just *..\jpeg*. Which is why we use

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AdditionalIncludeDirectories Include="..\jpeg;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

instead so the value is expanded to *..\jpeg;$(VCInstallPath)\include*.

Unrelated remark: usually you shouldn't be declaring include directories per file like that; suppose there's a second file which also needs that jpeg include path, you'd have to repeat yourself and write the same thing again. Repeating yourself in programming is nearly always wrong. Declaring the include path on the project level would be a good start. If you also don't want to repeat the same path across projects, look into using [property sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx#bkmkPropertySheets).

Comment: So it's about giving you the choice between adding to it or replacing it. I'm satisfied with that.

Comment: Well, often it is not really a choice: most of the time you don't want to replace compiler/linker flags, include paths, library paths etc.

Comment: There must be edge cases... not that i can think of any. If it was never needed they could have just made properties inherit from previous definitions by default without having to add the macro name.

Comment: @stijn I was running into the same issue. Does the order matter here? Any difference between your last example in your answer and `%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories);../jpeg`  where the order is reversed ? Does this have any different meaning?

Comment: @Tryer yes, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=msvc-170 etc, the compiler searches for include files in the order of include paths. In practice suppose jpeg.h is in ../jpeg and not in any of the other AdditionalIncludeDirectories, this doesn't matter. However if there are 2 or more jpeg.h files on your system and one is in AdditionalIncludeDirectories and the other in ../jpeg, then if ../jpeg comes after AdditionalIncludeDirectories the one in AdditionalIncludeDirectories will be found first and used